# Is it possible to write COM code in a static library and then link it to a DLL?

Tags: c++, dll, com, static-libraries, atl

I am currently working on a project that has a number of COM objects written in C++ with ATL.

Currently, they are all defined in .cpp and .idl files that are directly compiled into the COM DLL.

To allow unit tests to be written easier, I am planning on moving the implementation of the COM objects out into a separate static library.  That library can then be linked in to the main DLL, and the separate unit test project.

I am assuming that there's nothing particularly special about the code generated by ATL, and that this will work much like all other C++ code when it comes to linking with static libraries.  However, I don't have too much actual knowledge of ATL myself so don't know if this is really the case.

Will this work as I'm expecting?  Or are there pitfalls that I should look out for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are gotchas since LIBs are pulled in only if they are referenced, as opposed to OBJs which are explicitly included.

[Larry Osterman discussed some of the subtleties a few years ago](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/larryosterman/archive/2004/09/27/234840.aspx):

> **When I moved my code into a library, what happened to my ATL COM
>   objects?**
>
> A caveat: This post discusses details of how ATL7 works.  For other
>   version of ATL, YMMV.  The general principals apply for all
>   versions, but the details are likely to be different.
>
> My group’s recently been working on reducing the number of DLLs
>   that make up the feature we’re working on (going from somewhere
>   around 8 to 4).  As a part of this, I’ve spent the past couple of
>   weeks consolidating a bunch of ATL COM DLL’s.
>
> To do this, I first changed the DLLs to build libraries, and then
>   linked the libraries together with a dummy DllInit routine (which
>   basically just called `CComDllModule::DllInit()`) to make the DLL.
>
> So far so good.  Everything linked, and I got ready to test the new
>   DLL.
>
> For some reason, when I attempted to register the DLL, the
>   registration didn’t actually register the COM objects.  At that
>   point, I started kicking my self for forgetting one of the
>   fundamental differences between linking objects together to make an
>   executable and linking libraries together to make an executable.
>
> To explain, I’ve got to go into a bit of how the linker works.  When
>   you link an executable (of any kind), the linker loads all the
>   sections in the object files that make up the executable.  For each
>   extdef symbol in the object files, it starts looking for a public
>   symbol that matches the symbol.
>
> Once all of the symbols are matched, the linker then makes a second
>   pass combining all the .code sections that have identical contents
>   (this has the effect of collapsing template methods that expand into
>   the same code (this happens a lot with `CComPtr`)).
>
> Then a third pass is run. The third pass discards all of the
>   sections that have not yet been referenced.  Since the sections
>   aren’t referenced, they’re not going to be used in the resulting
>   executable, so to include them would just bloat the executable.
>
> Ok, so why didn’t my ATL based COM objects get registered?  Well,
>   it’s time to play detective.
>
> Well, it turns out that you’ve got to dig a bit into the ATL code to
>   figure it out.
>
> The ATL COM registration logic gets picked in the `CComModule`
>   object.  Within that object, there’s a method
>   `RegisterClassObjects`, which redirects to
>   `AtlComModuleRegisterClassObjects`.  This function walks a list of
>   `_ATL_OBJMAP_ENTRY` structures and calls the `RegisterClassObject`
>   on each structure.  The list is retrieved from the
>   `m_ppAutoObjMapFirst` member of the `CComModule` (ok, it’s really a
>   member of the `_ATL_COM_MODULE70`, which is a base class for the
>   `CComModule`).  So where did that field come from?
>
> It’s initialized in the constructor of the `CAtlComModule`, which
>   gets it from the `__pobjMapEntryFirst` global variable.  So where’s
>   `__pobjMapEntryFirst` field come from?
>
> Well, there are actually two fields of relevance,
>   `__pobjMapEntryFirst` and `__pobjMapEntryLast`.
>
> Here’s the definition for the `__pobjMapEntryFirst`:
>
> ```
>  __declspec(selectany) __declspec(allocate("ATL$__a")) _ATL_OBJMAP_ENTRY* __pobjMapEntryFirst = NULL;
> ```
>
> And here’s the definition for `__pobjMapEntryLast`:
>
> ```
>  __declspec(selectany) __declspec(allocate("ATL$__z")) _ATL_OBJMAP_ENTRY* __pobjMapEntryLast = NULL;
> ```
>
> Let’s break this one down:
>
> - `__declspec(selectany)`: `__declspec(selectany)` is a directive to
>     the linker to pick any of the similarly named items from the section
>     – in other words, if a `__declspec(selectany)` item is found
>     in multiple object files, just pick one, don’t complain about it
>     being multiply defined.
> - `__declspec(allocate("ATL$__a"))`: This one’s the one that makes
>     the magic work.  This is a declaration to the compiler, it tells the
>     compiler to put the variable in a section named `"ATL$__a"` (or
>     `"ATL$__z"`).
>
> Ok, that’s nice, but how does it work?
>
> Well, to get my ATL based COM object declared, I included the
>   following line in my header file:
>
> ```
>  OBJECT_ENTRY_AUTO(<my classid>, <my class>)
> ```
>
> `OBJECT_ENTRY_AUTO` expands into:
>
> ```
> #define OBJECT_ENTRY_AUTO(clsid, class) \
>
>         __declspec(selectany) ATL::_ATL_OBJMAP_ENTRY __objMap_##class = {&clsid, class::UpdateRegistry, class::_ClassFactoryCreatorClass::CreateInstance, class::_CreatorClass::CreateInstance, NULL, 0, class::GetObjectDescription, class::GetCategoryMap, class::ObjectMain }; \
>
>         extern "C" __declspec(allocate("ATL$__m")) __declspec(selectany) ATL::_ATL_OBJMAP_ENTRY* const __pobjMap_##class = &__objMap_##class; \
>
>         OBJECT_ENTRY_PRAGMA(class)
> ```
>
> Notice the declaration of `__pobjMap_##class` above – there’s
>   that `declspec(allocate("ATL$__m"))` thingy again.  And that’s where
>   the magic lies.  When the linker’s laying out the code, it sorts
>   these sections alphabetically – so variables in the `ATL$__a`
>   section will occur before the variables in the `ATL$__z` section.
>   So what’s happening under the covers is that ATL’s asking the linker
>   to place all the `__pobjMap_<class name>` variables in the
>   executable between `__pobjMapEntryFirst` and `__pobjMapEntryLast`.
>
> And that’s the crux of the problem.  Remember my comment above about
>   how the linker works resolving symbols?  It first loads all the items
>   (code and data) from the OBJ files passed in, and resolves all the
>   external definitions for them.  But none of the files in the wrapper
>   directory (which are the ones that are explicitly linked) reference
>   any of the code in the DLL (remember, the wrapper doesn’t do much more
>   than simply calling into ATL’s wrapper functions – it doesn’t
>   reference any of the code in the other files.
>
> So how did I fix the problem?  Simple.  I knew that as soon as the
>   linker pulled in the module that contained my COM class definition,
>   it'd start resolving all the items in that module.  Including the
>   `__objMap_<class>`, which would then be added in the right location so that ATL would be able to pick it up.  I put a dummy function call
>   called `ForceLoad<MyClass>` inside the module in the library, and
>   then added a function called `CallForceLoad<MyClass>` to my DLL 
>   entry point file (note: I just added the function – I didn’t
>   call it from any code).
>
> And voila, the code was loaded, and the class factories for my COM
>   objects were now auto-registered.
>
> What was even cooler about this was that since no live code called
>   the two dummy functions that were used to pull in the library, pass
>   three of the linker discarded the code!